# Magento category filters

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In Product listing page, Category filter comes by default. but when i select any category from category filter then it applies that category and remove category filter. 
is there any way to make category filter visible even after selecting a category

Answer (score 0):

By default it doesn't work in this way. You need to prepare custom logic for this functionality or you can use one of available 3rd party extensions.